# How to retrieve assets form Content Builder folder by categories parentId with REST API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I have four local folders in my Content Builder. Every folder has own assets. There is any way to retrieve assets by folder Id (categories id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the [asset category in REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm).

You likely could accomplish this via the [simple query version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetSimpleQuery.htm) and filter using the Category field.

Sample Call:
/asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=Category%20eq%20'123456'

Comment: There is any way to retrieve a specific asset by lagecyId?

Comment: do you mean to retrieve by using the ID linked to classic content? If so, you will likely need to use SOAP, not REST. REST is only for items inside of Content Builder. If you mean to retrieve items inside Content Builder by legacyId, I am not sure the use case, but in theory it should be possible.